# Is it possible to convert this map/filter code into list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a list of regular expressions I want to run over a single string. I don't care which expressions matched, I just want their results (re.Match objects).

Of course it's easy with the for loop, but I wanted something more pythonic. This is what I've got now:

```
all_matches = map(lambda x: x.match(domain), 
                  (first_re, second_re, third_re))
matches = [m for m in all_matches if m]
```

I feel under my skin, though, that it should be doable as a single comprehension. How should it look like, if it's possible at all?

Also, more generally - are list comprehensions equivalent to map/filter or do they just have a subset of m/f capabilities?

Comment: map/filter can do part of what a list comprehensions can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write this as a simple list comprehension. However, the `r.match(domain)` will have to be evaluated twice:

```
matches = [r.match(domain) for r in (first_re, second_re, third_re) if r.match(domain)]
```

Or you will have to write a double list comprehension:

```
matches = [a for a in (r.match(domain) for r in (first_re, second_re, third_re)) if a]
```

Comment: Double list comprehension - why didn't I think of that :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, filter/map can be written as a list comprehension (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) on this point). In this case, you can write `matches = [x.match(domain) for x in (first_re, second_re, third_re) if x.match(domain)]`.